# MongoDB: find in array of objects where items are only one value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

The data is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ae9f2188857ce20f516315c"),
    "meta" : {
        "participants" : [ 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "weiblich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.FEMALE"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "männlich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.MALE"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "weiblich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.FEMALE"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af00e1070bb5a707634cb12"),
    "meta" : {
        "participants" : [ 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "männlich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.MALE"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "männlich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.MALE"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5af1ef01cfd317006694a6e6"),
    "meta" : {
        "participants" : [ 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "weiblich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.FEMALE"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "gender" : [ 
                    {
                        "text" : "weiblich",
                        "id" : "LABEL.FEMALE"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So `meta.participants` contains some items with different properties e.g. `gender` with is also an array of one item (don't ask, historic reasons; it's always one item, never two and never empty).

I need a query which returns the documents which contains only male participants (the second doc `5af00e1070bb5a707634cb12`).

I already tried my luck but I can't get it right.

These queries give me every doc which has a male participant:

```
{'meta.participants.gender.id': 'LABEL.MALE'}
{'meta.participants.gender': { $elemMatch: {id: 'LABEL.MALE'}}}
```

These queries give me 0 results..

```
{'meta.participants.gender': {id: 'LABEL.MALE'}}
{'meta.participants.gender[0]': { $elemMatch: {id: 'LABEL.MALE'}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "meta.participants": {
    "$not": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "gender.id": {
          "$nin": [
            "LABEL.MALE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: since there is only 1 criteria, the `$elemMatch` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The query to retrieve documents with `gender.id` field do not have `LABEL.FEMALE`.

```
db.test.find( { "meta.participants.gender.id": { $ne: "LABEL.FEMALE" } } )
```

As such you don't need to use the `$elemMatch` for [Single Query Condition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html#single-query-condition) (but, it not an error *and* the results will be same).